# How to add to your array in xml through your java file android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I have an array of Strings (one item) called "athlete_array" but I want to add to this array through an Activity java file called CreateTeamActivity. Is there a way I can create a method in the CreateTeamActivity class to add to this array? (This code is located in res/values/strings.xml) I might be wrong in thinking there IS a way to do this but if anyone has a similar way to accomplish the same goal I would appreciate it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Track and Field Team Builder</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="title_activity_create_team">CreateTeamActivity</string>
    <string-array name="athlete_array">
        <item>Shuttle Badminton</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

String resources are static and cannot be manipulated by Java code. Instead, you should just use a `String[]`, or better yet a `List<String>`. If you need to persist the data, then you will need to use a SQLite database or `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: Alright thanks I was originally going to use the string array for a listview but since arrays are definite Lists would be better. Also in retrospect the Strings.xml in the res folder seems like it WOULD be something not meant to be tampered with, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

From your Activity, call:

```
String[] athleteArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.athlete_array);
```

Comment: The question is how to add or remove strings from the XML resource.